# htaccess excluding 1 folder from rewriterules

Tags: http, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, directory

Depending on my value IS_HTTP, I decide after the code below, whether URL should be https or http.

I want always http (redirected from https) for `http://mydomain.com` (has an empty QUERY_STRING), `http://mydomain.com/?q=home`, `http://mydomain.com/?qq=home`. 
And the code below works fine for such URLs, it sets up IS_HTTP to 1. Everything is perfect. But I want also URLs to administration folder always to be httpS, so I want to exclude such URLs from that block.

That's why I added the second string to the code below, but it doesn't stop such URLs from applying `RewriteRule ^ - [E=IS_HTTP:1]`. Why?

```
#determine if page is supposed to be http
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^administration [NC]
#if it has q=home or qq=home in querystring
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)(q=home|qq=home)(&|$) [NC,OR]
#or if query string is empty
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
#set env var to 1
RewriteRule ^ - [E=IS_HTTP:1]
```

Again, I want `https://mydomain.com/administration/index.php` and all other files from the folder /administration to be stopped before `RewriteRule ^ - [E=IS_HTTP:1]`
Why the code above does NOT stop them?

The second string I've tried was:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^administration [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/administration [NC]
```

but none of them works. (I believe / is not needed here as REQUEST_URI doesn't start from /, but I could be wrong).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^administration [NC]
```

have this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/+administration [NC]
```

Remember that `%{REQUEST_URI}` always starts with a slash and can have multiple slashes if it is typed that way in browser.